# I have two Ubuntu Software Centers, one can be opened, another one can't

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, software-center

Recently my Ubuntu Software Center could not be opened(it opens showing nothing and exit automatically). I therefore ran the command `sudo apt-get remove software-center` to remove the Ubuntu Software Center. then I use `sudo apt-get install software-center` to reinstall it.

Now I have two Ubuntu software Centers; one is called "Ubuntu Software"(default broken one), another is called "Ubuntu Software Center"(the current working one).

The problem I have is that whenever I want to download something not in the Software Center, if I open the .deb file, the broken one opens it, and closes very quickly. Basically I can't download anything outside the Ubuntu Software Center for that reason.

My current Ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 16.04LTS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 16.04, `Ubuntu Software Center` (`ubuntu-software-center`) was replaced by `Software Install` (`gnome-software`, or simply "Software" in Dash).

Most likely you had some left overs after upgrading from `14.04`to `16.04`. Subsequently, you reinstalled the old `Ubuntu Software Center`, while the newer `gnome-software` was also installed.

#### What to do

Since we do not know for sure what exactly happened and why, do the following:

1. Run the command

   ```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove software-center
   ```
2. Look into both `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/applications` if you find any left-over `.desktop` files, named `ubuntu-software-center.desktop`, remove them if so.
3. Run

   ```
    sudo apt-get install gnome-software
   ```

After that, log out and back in to make sure, and `gnome-software` ("Software" in Dash) should be the only one.

Comment: Maybe remove all traces and purge (`sudo apt-get --purge remove software-center`) it? And also remove old dependencies (`sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edit. `sudo apt-get --purge remove software-center` is fine. Not sure if `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove` is the safest wau to prevent new issues though.

Comment: Sorry, copied a bit to much from the previous code. Of course this would be problematic in case the dependencies need to be reinstalled.